# Difference in doc created by agent vs gui QuerySave fails to allow ODBC transfer

Tags: lotus-notes

After I create a doc in a Notes app, I'm moving information from that doc to a postgres db.
The agent that transfers the data to postgres uses a field in the doc as the key field.

I'm running into the following problem:
- If I create the doc via the Notes client, the transfer occurs without problems.
- If I create the doc from an agent (which processes an incoming email and generates a valid key field value), the transfer fails with a null key error.  If I then open and save the doc, the transfer is successful.

I key field value is not null, however.  I can see it in the view, in the document, and in the document properties.

Any thoughts on how I might be able to figure this out would be appreciated.
thanks!
clem

============================

Thanks Torsten for the reply.  I appreciate it.  Well, there's not much to the code, really.  Here's part of it.  "x.LogNumber" returns a string.  The format is something like T1234CP.  I ended up adding the computeWithForm and setting the IsSummary tho I don't think it was necessary.

```
atdoc.logNumber = x.LogNumber

Call atdoc.computeWithForm(false, false)
Dim lnItem As NotesItem
Set lnItem = atDoc.getfirstitem("logNumber")
lnItem.IsSummary=True       
Call atdoc.save(True, False)
```

=======================================
 Once the doc is created, an agent runs that transfers some data from the doc to the postgres db via odbc:

```
'.. define the 'key field' to be use in the connection.select call 
Dim selectFldLst As New LCFieldList
'.. add the key field name to the LCfieldList object.
Call selectFldLst.Append(NotesKeyFieldName, LCTYPE_TEXT)
'.. set this field to be the key field.
selectFldLst.Getfield(1).flags = LCFIELDF_KEY       

Set Notes_LCFieldList = New LCFieldList ' flSrc
Set odbcDB_LCfieldList = New LCFieldList ' flDest
'.. get the key of the doc to transfer.     
Set docWithTransferID = docsToTransferViewEntry.Document            
selectFldLst.LogNumber = Trim(docWithTransferID.stid(0)) 
count = Notes_LCConnection.Select(selectFldLst, 1, Notes_LCFieldList)
                        ^--- This selects the fields from the Notes document.  This is where it fails.  It returns 0 for 'count'.  It should return 1.  If I save the document manually, it works.
```

Comment: In Notes client the doc is created in QuerySave event the same way the agent creates it? So the document/form is not open in Notes client?

Comment: The doc IS open in the Notes client.  The key field is populated in the PostOpen event.  The user fills out some fields and saves the doc.  The only thing I do in the QuerySave event is to flag the doc for transfer.  When it's created via email, the key field is generated in the email processing agent and the other fields are populated by the contents of the email.

Comment: I know you say you see it in the view, but NotesPeek is still the ultimate authority IMHO.  I'd use NotesPeek to compare an agent-created and manually-created message. And be sure to check that the item type is what you expect.  If everything still looks right in NotesPeek, then I think we'll need to see the code in order to find additional suggestions.

Comment: Hey Rich.  I checked NotesPeek and the doc created via the email does have the key field set correctly and still generates the error.  I then opened and saved and it went through as expected.

Comment: Looks like you need to post your code which creates the doc (especially key item) and the code that reads it.

Comment: I can't post much of the code but I did create a simplified version that shows the same behavior.

It fails on the next line.  If I don't save the document via the Notes i/f, the count comes back as zero.  If I save it, the count is 1.

 count = Notes_LCConnection.Select(selectFldLst, 1, Notes_LCFieldList)

Comment: Can you also post the code which returns null value for item "logNumber".

Comment: Sorry, but your code examples do not match... in the first you write "atdoc.logNumber = x.LogNumber", but in the second code example it sais "selectFldLst.LogNumber = Trim(docWithTransferID.stid(0))". So you SET logNumber, but you READ stid ... Just a Typo for the examples?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your form is doing something to it. As a quick and dirty fix you could try `doc.computeWithForm()` in your agent before saving.

Comment: Hi Panu.  I actually had a computeWithForm in the code originally and took it out.  I added it back in just in case and that did not make a difference.  I'll have to do some more tests tho.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You create the records from Notes? Save yourself the trouble with code in the events and configure DECS. It creates the document for you reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I had started that way but there's no connector for postgres.

Comment: There is standard ODBC. So Step 1 is to have a working ODBC connection

Comment: Oh... yeah, that's what i'm doing.  i'll post more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the items in the document you create do not have the "Summary" property set. That makes them "invisible" for some functions / subs...

Please provide some code about how you create the items. If you do it like `Set item = New Item(doc, "Name", "Value")` then the item will not be summary. Then you need to call a `item.issummary = true`

Taking into account the last comments I guess, that the agent sets the item with the wrong datatype. Again: The code of the agent would have helped to identify this. 
If for example the Field in the document is of type text and the agent writes something like 
`docWithTransferID.stid = 1` then everything "seems" to be OK, as the field is shown correctly in the views and in the Form. But in the Properties of the document it will be shown as number. As soon as you save the document, the design of the form will force it to be a Text.

The same thing works vice versa. If the agent reads the data from a textfile (e.g) and does something like `docWithTransferID.stid = "1"`, then the item will be text, no matter how it is defined in the Form. As soon as you save the document -> Voila, it will be a number again.

Background LotusScript does not know ANYTHING about the Form and therefor does not obey datatypes or formats... You have to take care for this yourself.

Comment: Note: "I can see it in the view".

Comment: Ok... Then it in deed is summary... Thanx for clarification

Comment: Thanks for the ideas!  Still not working.  I even set the isSummary flag.  The behavior persists: If I create the document from the agent,  it generates the error " null value in column "lognumber" violates not-null constraint".  If I then go into the document and save it, the transfer is successful.  I will try and create a simplified version of the transfer agent so I could post the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Odd, I posted this yesterday but don't see it.<br/>
 selectFldLst.LogNumber = docWithTransferID.stid(0) <br/>
 count = Notes_LCConnection.Select(selectFldLst, 1, Notes_LCFieldList)<br/>
...When the doc is created via Notes, count=1 (it finds the Notes doc).  If it's created via the agent, count=0 (doc not found).  If I edit/save the doc created by the agent, count=1 (doc found)

Comment: Hi Torsten. I took your idea of editing my post so I can use a descent editor.  So, I've updated my initial entry with a bit more code.